# Ubuntu 13.10 duplicates my key presses

Tags: keyboard, 13.10

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 and it now constantly duplicates my key presses when I am in a browser, HUD or libreoffice. So if I type "ubuntu" it types "uubbuunnttuu". When I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> it eliminates two chars at once. The only exception is terminal. It behaves as usual. The problem is very frustrating, I can't get to work with it, please halp me.

Comment: Try to mess around with System Settings > Keyboard, you can configure keystroke repeating there. Maybe this already helps.

Comment: This just started happening to me too.  I have no idea what caused it.  It's happening if I boot to a console as well, not just in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your keyboard settings got a little out of whack. Try this:

1. Open your System Settings, either through the Dash of that little cog on the top right corner of your desktop:
   [image: Desktop]
2. Open the keyboard settings:
   [image: System Settings]
3. Look at the Repeat Keys settings (under the mouse cursor). Try sliding the "Delay" option towards "Long". You may also like to set "Speed" more closely to "Slow". An extreme alternative would be to disable "Key presses repeat when key is held down", which would require you to press a key once for every sequential repetition you want of it. 
   [image: Keyboard]

Comment: Thank you, Waldir. Actually I tried this before, but forgot to mention it in the question. It doesn't help either. Nor delaying and speeding down key presses repetition, nor disabling it at all.